# Why individually rendered form fields not posting in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-class-based-views

I have a class based UpdateView that works fine if I render the form as `{{ form.as_p }}`. It updating the values, but looks bad.

If I try to render the fields individually it does not updating the values.

I can't figure out how to fix it, I'm not so familiar with class based views. I don't think there is a validation error (i don't know how to check it in class based views) because `{{ form.as_p }}` works well.
Thank you in advance if someone can help me out!

**models.py**

```
class LeaderFeedback(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)

    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="employed")
    leader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employer_leader")

    goals01 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    goals01_deadline = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    goals01_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    leader_comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateLeaderFeedbackView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = LeaderFeedback
    form_class = PeriodicLeaderFeedbackForm
    template_name = 'performance/periodic/leader_feedback_edit.html
```

**forms.py**

```
class Meta:
    model = LeaderFeedback
    fields = '__all__'
    
    goals_value =(
        (1, "Nem teljesült"),
        (2, "Részben teljesült"),
        (3, "Megfelelő"),
        (4, "Maximálisan teljesült"),
        )
            
    widgets = {            
        'goals01_value': forms.RadioSelect(choices=goals_value),
        'leader_comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":"3", 'class': 'form-control'}),
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'performance'
urlpatterns = [

    ...
    path('periodic/leader_feedback_edit/<pk>', login_required(UpdateLeaderFeedbackView.as_view()), name='update_leaderfeedback'),
    ...
```

**leader_feedback_edit.html**

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="card shadow p-2 my-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h6 class="">Cél 1:</h6>
                {{ object.goals01 }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h6 class="">Kitűzött határidő:</h6>
                {{ object.goals01_deadline }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h6 class="">Értékelés:</h6>
                 {{ form.goals01_value }}
         </div>
         {{ form.leader_comment }}
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info my-3"></input>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If a form is invalid in an `UpdateView`, it will call the function `form_invalid(form)`. You can  then print the errors using `print(form.errors)`. You can add that to see if the form is getting validated or not.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but did not print any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to include in your HTML form tags.
Also, you need to take care of csrf_token.

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="card shadow p-2 my-2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h6 class="">Cél 1:</h6>
            {{ object.goals01 }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h6 class="">Kitűzött határidő:</h6>
            {{ object.goals01_deadline }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h6 class="">Értékelés:</h6>
             {{ form.goals01_value }}
     </div>
     {{ form.leader_comment }}
 </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. Form and csrf are there. I just forgot to paste them here. Thank you, I'm edited the question and included them.

Comment: You include all fields in the form. In the code you shared you assign for form only those : "leader_comment", "goals01_value".  "goals01" and "goals01_deadline" are not considered as forms here. On top of this you have also "employee" and "leader" which are not assigned at all. Most probably you want to assign them somewhere in the views, if they should not be rendered in the HTML. Most probably form is not validated with success as you are simply missing all required fields in form.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't know I have to add all the fields. Thank you very much! ;)